# Django - models - access a value of a field within a class

Tags: python, django, model, field

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    '''Items have tag will have according discount percentage'''

    tag_discount_percentage = models.IntegerField()

    slogan_default = 'Purchase NOW for extra {}% off!'.format(tag_discount_percentage.get_prep_value(value))

    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=slogan_default)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slogan
```

This code raised exception:

> slogan_default = 'Purchase NOW for the extra {}%
>   off!'.format(tag_discount_percentage.get_prep_value(value)) NameError:
>   name 'value' is not defined

urggg!

#### Question 1: How does one access a field's own value within that class? Or is there a better way to set the default of a CharField?

`tag_discount_percentage` itself is `<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField>` but I want the value

---

#### Question 2: Could I set a digit limitation to an `IntegerField`? all I found was `max_length` which prompts a warning saying that 'max_length will be ignored'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Attempt to answer Question 1:

I'm not sure if this is the best answer but it solved the problem. It seems that it's not possible (or I simply do not know how) to access the value of a field within the class so I figured something else:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    '''Items have tag will have according discount percentage'''
    tag_discount_percentage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slogan if self.slogan else self.slogan_default

    @property
    def slogan_default(self):
        return 'Purchase NOW for the extra {}% off!'.format(self.tag_discount_percentage)
```

Erm.. **I'd really appreciate if anyone could answer Question 2.** Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

Answering your second question - it's not obvious what you mean by "digit limitation". If you are interested in preventing the value from being out of defined ranges, then you can use [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator):

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class Tag(models.Model):
    '''Items have tag will have according discount percentage'''
    tag_discount_percentage = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

Else, if you meant to limit decimal places, then you should use a [decimal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) field instead of integer.

Also, commenting on your first question - you simply can't set the default related with value of another field because on the moment when instance(record) is saved, field values isn't set up yet. `default` agrument can be a callable, but without any reference to an objects it's being used for. You may consider using [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal instead to set a field value "by default" depending on another fields.